# How to get DocumentSnapshot while there is no connectivity in device with firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

After many tried, I come over here,
As per the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#access-data-offline):

> Firestore provides out of the box support for offline capabilities.
> When reading and writing data, Firestore uses a local database which
> automatically synchronizes with the server. Cloud Firestore
> functionality continues when users are offline, and automatically
> handles data migration when they regain connectivity.

So, I write some code in `iniState()`

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(AppString.FB_USERS)
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document exists on the database');
      }
      else{
        print('Document not exists on the database');
      }
    });
```

It is work fine.

But when I closed my internet connection, and remove app from recent than come back my app,
Its not work in offline

**Correction 1**

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(AppString.FB_USERS).doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache)).then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document exists on the database');
      }
    });
```

If I used only `get()` instead of `get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache))` than it will never return data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get()` call first tries to get the latest data from the server, and it may take some time for that check to fail. Only once it fails does it return data from the cache. So I expect that you'll need to wait a bit longer than you did.

Alternatively you can [listen for updates](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes), which gives you a stream that will immediately give you the local version of the document (if any) and then will call your code again if there is any update from the server.

Comment: get() is return FutureBuilder not a streamBuilder.

Comment: local version of the document (if any)....means if device has connectivity than get data from server otherwise get data from cache , am I right ?

Comment: and get() is only get data from server , it will not get data automatically  from cache until i will not specified get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache)) , please see my corrected question

Comment: `get()` without options should first try to load data from the server, and then (when it realizes it can't reach the server) check the cache. If it's not doing the latter, that'd be a bug.

Comment: yes, you are right, according to this https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/GetOptions-class.html

Comment: If indeed you never get the cached version when calling `get()` even after waiting for a long time, I'd recommend filing a bug on the relevant repo: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire. You can of course also submit a PR with a fix. :)     If it is indeed a bug, then until a fix lands in a release, you can use `onSnapshot` to get all values, or `get` with options to always get the value from the cache.