# How to implement "message not delivered" on a Flutter Firestore chat application

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

## TL;DR

I'm listening to Firestore changes using a snapshot. Snapshots documents are [from cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68734974/12695188). How can I indicate whether a DocumentSnapshot has delivered or not? Is there any flag which can indicate it?

### More info

I'm developing a chat application, and I want to implement a "message not delivered" icon next to the message, same as WhatsApp does (on no network connection).

[image]

I'm using Firestore to collect my messages, and I'm listening to updates using a snapshot. Since I'm using Firestore snapshot, I'm getting my messages [from the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68734974/12695188), while the cache itself updates on every change (which is pretty cool).

My issue is that I cannot indicate whether each message was delivered successfully or not.

A good use case is a user, with no network connection, that is sending a message, then closes the app, and re-opens it (without any network, cached only). I need to indicate to them that the last message has still not been delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag [`document.metadata.hasPendingWrites`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata#haspendingwrites) indicates whether the document was delivered or not.